# Use Blat to send mail, why time send is one hour ahead than time received?

Tags: windows, date-time

Use [BlatJ](http://www.piedey.co.jp/blatj/) (Japanese version of [Blat](http://www.blat.net)) to send email, the command is:

```
blatJ test.txt -t recipient@example.com -s "test from blatj" -f sender@example.com
```

I sent the mail at **09:30**, and received by outlook 2010 immediately.

The ***received time*** show in outlook is **09:30**, 
while the ***send time*** is **08:30**

I check the date and time setting, it is correctly set to **UTC+09:00** Tokyo.

However I check the email header, it has the following line:

```
Received: ...; Thu, 27 Oct 2016 10:46:42 +0900 (JST) 
Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2016 10:46:46 +1000
```

the Date header is not correct, it should be +0900.

I think the problem is with the OS (Windows), not blat. But why?

Comment: What are the time zone setting of the sender and the receiver?